# Why VScode creating new line on entering each character?

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline, automatic-semicolon-insertion

While typing each character, vscode puts a semicolon and move to the next line.
Here I used to type 'import' but it appears as ' i; m; p; o; r; t; '.
How can I solve this problem?

[This is how the characters appear on vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUWZH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a JavaScript file (ends with .js) and your JavaScript settings are auto-formatting the code.

Comment: It happens for all sort of files, not just for `.js` files in my case. Restarting doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this issue still, you most likely have autosave on type enabled along with the option to format on each save so this creates a chain of formatting and saving which can lead to the problem. I solved this issue by either disabling auto-save or by disabling format on save option.